# How do I show that $P(B\cap C)\ge0.1$ Given the information $P(A)=0.25, P(B)=0.5, P(C)=0.6, P(A\cup B) =0.55, P(A\cap C)=0.1$

Tags: probability

How do I show that $P(B\cap C)\ge0.1$ Given the information $P(A)=0.25, P(B)=0.5, P(C)=0.6, P(A\cup B) =0.55, P(A\cap C)=0.1$

I've tried to use $P(A\cap C)= -P( B\cup C) +P(A) + P(C)$ but get that $P(B \cap C) \le 0.9$ I've also tried to approach it by saying that $P(A\cup B \cup C) \le 1)$ But have had no successes, can I have something to help me.

Comment: The condition $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is not useful if you just calculate $\mathbb{P}(B\cap C)$. Please see the solution by @trancelocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B \cup C) = P(B) + P(C) - P(B \cap C) \leq 1 \Rightarrow P(B \cap C) \geq P(B) + P(C) - 1$$